# Is it a future simple tense or present progressive tense?

Tags: grammar

> "I am going to do the work"

I know this sentence works like future though it has *"am"* and (verb+ing) which is the characteristic of present progressive. Can I say it is a future simple tense?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, no, this is not the future simple tense: [the simple future is made with *will*, like "I will do the work."](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-future-tense/)

But you're correct that ["to be going to" is a construction that we use to talk about future plans](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/future-going/).

The difference is that you can use "to be going to" in the past, but you can't use "will" in the past.

> He was going to do the work.  (good)
>   <strike>He was will do the work.</strike> (wrong)

---

An interesting note:
[Technically, English does not have a future tense at all!](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-English-not-have-a-future-tense)  We have a present tense (I *work*) and a past tense (I *worked*) that are made with verb inflection (conjugation) but we don't have a future tense that you can make the same way.  Instead, we have a *periphrastic* construction that we use like a future tense (I *will* work) that uses *will* as a modal, exactly like *can*, *should*, *might*, *may*, etc. and we also have a number of other constructions that we can use to talk about various aspects of the future.